# ngx admin redirect if user session expire on server side

Tags: angular, authentication, angular6

I'm using ngx admin with it's nebular auth in Angular 6. Backend is in Laravel and using APIs for communication with each other.

My issue is when user stay inactive for a long time, his session expire on server but he still can navigate to angular pages with no data in them as API gives 401 Unauthorized error.

Is there any default way in this admin theme which provide this feature to check user login status and redirect him to logout page? Please guide.

**I didn't added code here as I don't know which files you guys might want to see. So let me know if you need anything else.**

Comment: I dont know about default props, in this theme, but you can always you the native angular interceptors to redirect the user to the login page, whenever 401 is returned from the server.

Comment: can you guide me what these interceptors are or any example to tutorials? I've just started angular so don't know much.

Comment: I think this is a good one https://alligator.io/angular/httpclient-interceptors/ , basicly all http calls to the server and their responses are streams, so the idea behind the interceptor is to catch the response and based on that response to do some stuff (in your case logout or redirect action) ,  before passing it to the app.

Comment: @UmairMalik did you every get the solution to this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @Strategist i created my own guard which check user login status and if user is logged out it clear it from local storage which make it logout from angular too. Moreover I did these changes for custom authentication, 

https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/auth/configuring-ui#custom-ui-components

Comment: @Strategist if you follow through that link which I shared then hopefully you will get what you need. Good luck!

Comment: @UmairMalik Could you please tell which behaviour did you exactly override (`NbAuthService`)?